# Why is my if function closing my batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Whenever I activate this code it instantly closes the console.

```
set RAND=%RANDOM% %%100
if %RAND% gtr '25'
```

I want it to keep running if the if is false or go to an alternative location if it is true.

Comment: are you sure your batch file is getting close because of the code snippet you provided?

Comment: See `set /?` its very obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two lines of code - four problems

```
set RAND=%RANDOM% %%100
if %RAND% gtr '25'
```

First, to set a variable to the result of a calculation, you need `set /a`. As it stands, `rand` would be set to `12345 %100` - a string (one `%` because `%` escapes `%`)

Your second line would then be invoked as

```
if 12345 %100 gtr '25'
```

which violates the `if` syntax - the `%100` would confuse it as it expects a comparison operator (==, equ, neq, gtr, lss, leq, geq) in that position so it will generate an error message and stop. If you're running using point, click and giggle then the window will instantly close. You need to run batch programs from the command prompt while debugging.

Next problem is that `25` is never going to be equal to `'25'` - the quotes are part of the string being compared. put them on both sides or omit them from both sides. Batch only uses strings - the `set /a` syntax understands and controls the conversion operations required to change from string to numeric representation (integers only) and the `if` will attempt to convert arguments to numeric for comparison - on failure of either side, `if` reverts to a string-comparison.

And finally, you've not provided `if` with anything to do should the comparison have evaluated to `true` - which is another violation of the `if` structure.

Answer (score 0):

Put pause at the end of the file... Pause doesn't allow the batch file to close unless you press a key (like Spacebar).

```
@echo off
cls
echo This is just an example
pause
exit
```

Comment: Unfortunately wrong in this case. If there is a heavy syntacticall error like a missing closing paranthesis it will crash nevertheless. If you copy the questions code into a batch-file and place a pause at the end of the file, you can barely read the error message as the window closes. The only way to prevent closing is running the whole thing from a command prompt

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Haha! I don't use batch files often to be honest. This will work *perfectly*, though, if you're making a very simple batch file. I neglected to look at the code and just figured everything was right. I just assumed that he forgot to put "pause" at the end.

Comment: But the chance that you have a batch-file that does not include `if` or `for` with potential syntactical errors is very small... For debugging you should always run the batch from the command prompt as Magoo mentions in his answer. "I neglected to look at the code and ..."; Big mistake! Usually the problem is in the code and not the headline... Please only post tested things as answer or things where you are to 100% sure it is working...

Comment: @geisterfurz007 You've got to realize CMD code, or Batch File code isn't nearly as common as HTML, JavaScript, Java, etc. I'm personally more familiar with HTML and JavaScript, but, my point is, Batch is pretty uncommon. I mean, one of the only times you're going to use a batch file is to fix your computer, and maybe not even that. If you want to do some advanced stuff with command prompts, you're not going to use CMD, and you're likely not even going to use Windows as an OS. In fact, the best CMD on Windows is Windows Power Shell, not something like CMD.

Comment: True fact! It is (compared to others) fairly uncommon. Still there is something wrong there. There are people building text-adventures, quizes and other small games with batch. As an addition to python my friend asked me to help him with something because nothing is as system-close as batch. And I believe that fixing the computer is one of the smaller parts of what you do with batch. More likely it is file-management. Having a look on the questions of SO proves that. I need to sort my files, add folders, delete them.

Comment: My point however is that questions about uncommon languages should be answered by those who knoe them well. I could not go ahead and try to answer more complex html questions, simply because I have no idea of it... It might bring confusion to those who read it.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 They're actually creating "command prompt" applications using C++, C#, VB.Net, stuff like that. It only runs like a batch file. Honestly, I haven't seen anything advanced like "text-adventures" using batch files. I have, however, seen things like that made with these programming languages built with Visual Studio. - And you're right. I could not go and answer something like a Java or C++ question just because I don't know too much about it. I am only a 'rookie' at Batch, also, but I know it's limits. I probably should've done a little more research before attempting to answer.